# Verify not only internet connection but if it is passing data - XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having a problem with this verification of the internet connection. See I have this verification in my code:

```
  if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
  {
     ...
  }
```

It works, but I think there is a situation that this do not cover, I have a shopping right next door to my office, I enter the shopping and the device just connects with the shopping WI-FI, but it's not passing data, because it need's to login in the session to get free WI-FI from the shopping.

So my question in resume is, is there a way, not only to verify if the device is conected to the internet, but if it is passing data through the connection?

Comment: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html Perhaps  each time after the connection changes, you can ping, say google.com, and see if theres a response. Although make sure your userbase isn't in China, where Google is blocked haha.

Comment: @sme "Although make sure your userbase isn't in China, where Google is blocked haha" good one.

Comment: @Dbl Yeah, its true though haha.. maybe ping bing.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this solution but it might help you.

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
 if (ConnectGoogle())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
      //
    }  
}
```

`ConnectGoogle` method

```
public bool ConnectGoogle()
{
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://www.google.com").OpenConnection());
        urlc.SetRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.SetRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.ConnectTimeout = 10000;
        urlc.Connect();
        return (urlc.ResponseCode == HttpStatus.Accepted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: One of the issues of using a hostname is a captured portal typically redirects all DNS requests to the portal until you are logged/accepted the TOS/...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Net.WebClient` and test open/read an url. Also another way could be to ping a resource that is theoritically never offline. i.e. google.

Something like:

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    try { 
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        String host = "google.com";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 1000;
        PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success){
            // Your code here...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I see all answers work in my situation, but I used this method from https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html, you could open it or just see it down here:

```
 var verificaPassagemDados = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("google.com");
```

Thanks @sme